# Using Ninject on a Wcf workflow Hosted On IIS

Tags: wcf, workflow, ninject

Am quite new to using Ninject on WCF and WF and am currently stuck on how can i use property injection on a CodeActivity Class
Example

```
public sealed class TestInjection : CodeActivty
{

    [Inject]
    public IRepository Repository { get; set; }


    // Define an activity input argument of type string
    public InArgument<string> Text { get; set; }

    // If your activity returns a value, derive from CodeActivity<TResult>
    // and return the value from the Execute method.
    protected override void Execute(CodeActivityContext context)
    {
        // Obtain the runtime value of the Text input argument
        string text = context.GetValue(this.Text);
        var name = Repository.GetSomeNAme(); ///Repository is always Null/ never gets injected
    }
}
```

Please help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the WF extension:

https://github.com/ninject/ninject.extensions.wf

https://github.com/ninject/ninject.extensions.wf/wiki